# Parsing PHP content in HTML without Webserver

Tags: php, html, server-side

I want to create a simple webiste with only html pages. I am now including Header, sidebar, footer in every file, which is redundant. So, while looking for solution, I found `<?php include`, can help me. But my browser is not parsing php content. How can I make it parse php files in html?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your goal is to create a simple HTML website, with static pages I don't think PHP is the best way to go.

You have two options:

**Run PHP on your local computer to pre-process the files:**

If you install PHP-cli (command line client), you can use it to process your PHP static pages. Redirect its output to a file and you have your desired output:

```
php-cli index.php > index.html
```

**Use nanoc (ruby-based) to build your static website:**

If you don't have a webserver with PHP enabled, I assume you do not have PHP as a requirement but rather found about `<?php include('file') ?>` while studying HTML.

With this in mind, I suggest you check out **[nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/1-introduction/)**. It's a tool what uses ruby to help creating static HTML webpages, by providing ways to define a layout (what you're doing with PHP's `include`) and many other features.

It's quite simple to use and produces static HTML files that you can upload to any server or open with your browser directly and still enables many powerful features while developing your website.

Comment: out of curiosity, are you opting for php-cli or nanoc? I highly recommend nanoc, but I'm a big fan of ruby so I'm biased :)

Comment: I am thinking of php-cli, as I know little of php.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have PHP installed on the server that is running the website. You need to make sure you are naming your files with a valid php extension, e.g. index.php. Can you give us a link to your website where the issue is occurring?

Comment: Yes, I am using .php extension. Actually my content is local yet, so there it is not public viewable. Here is how I included htm file <?php include("scripts.htm"); ?>

Comment: You need to have PHP installed and have a web server running such as Apache. You should install WAMP (google it).

Comment: what if I don't want to install webserver? is there any other way?

Comment: No, the web server needs to process the file before sending it to your browser. You can always develop on a web hosting account.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter www.example.com/test.php in the addressbar,the browser contacts the webserver at www.example.com and requests for the file /test.php. Now depending on how your server is configured, you web server will detect the type of the file (usually using the extension). In this case (since the extension is .php), the webserver will detect that the file is a PHP script and will invoke the PHP interpreter. The PHP interpreter will execute the script and generate HTML which is passed on to the web server. Now the web server will return the HTML to the browser.

- PHP is a [*mainly*](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2004/07/14/client-side-php-in-internet-explorer/) (**Yes, it is possible to run PHP within browser**) a server side language
- This means PHP is not executed in you browser, but on your server
- Therefore, you need to have PHP configured correctly on your server to see the correct output
- Even if you manage to configure PHP as client side language on your system, remember there is not even < 1% change of your user's browser supporting it.
- You can only have webpages, and not website, without a web server

> A website (also spelled Web site) is a collection of related web pages, images, videos or other digital assets that are addressed relative to a common Uniform Resource Locator (URL), often consisting of only the domain name (or, in rare cases, the IP address) and the root path ('/') in an Internet Protocol-based network. A web site is hosted on at least one web server, accessible via a network such as the Internet or a private local area network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a web server set up with PHP running on it. PHP is an acronym for "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor". PHP is processed on the server, rendered into HTML content, then sent out of a web browser to be viewed, but no web browser has the ability to processor PHP on its own.

Here are some resources to get you started:

[PHP: What do I need?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.requirements.php)

[Your First PHP-enabled Page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php)

Comment: So, I have to install web server in any case. is it?

Comment: @Ringo - Yes, you need to install a web server; however, that web server can run on any old PC. If you're running Windows, check out the WAMP project (mentioned in the comments above). If you're running OS X, search for MAMP.

Comment: Thanks, it is not a problem for me to install webserver. Just wanted to try without webserver.

Comment: @Ringo To complement Matt V.'s answer, the server can also run on the computer you are using yourself, it does not have to be a separate machine.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. More or less I want static pages, so webserver should be a useless burden for my system.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser cannot interpret / parse php files.

If you want to test your site locally, you will need to install a local server like [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php) for windows or apache and php in linux.