# PHP Creating and editing TXT file

Tags: php, file, store

I have tried everything, and multiple different source codes, I have tried creating the file so all the PHP had to do was write in it, and still unable to do it.

This is my HTML on index.html

```
<form name="userinput" action="usersave.php" method="post">
Your name: <input type="text" name="username><br>
Your email: <input type="text" name="useremail"><br>
Your story: <textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="userstory"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" name="submit">
</form>
```

And this is my PHP on usersave.php

```
<header>
<?php
    $file = 'output.txt';
    $buffer = $_POST['userstory'];

    if (file_exists($file)) {
            $buffer = file_get_contents($file) . "\n" . $buffer;
    }

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $buffer);
?>
</header>
```

any help is appreciated, please and thank you.

Comment: Any errors or pertinent log file information?

Comment: Have you got some permissions errors?

Comment: I am not using any host whatsoever and am opening the files directly from my PC into Chrome. Unsure about any of the above.

Comment: You mean, *Windows Explorer > YourFolder > thisfile.php > Open File*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: You'll need to install some sort of server environment to get started.

I recommend [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: I am not using any host whatsoever and am opening the files directly from my PC into Chrome. Unsure about any of the above.

Comment: Your using windows I assume (chown -R www-data:www-data /dir/to/www/ is not for windows) hold on.. ill post you an exmaple code on how to read / write / to file using php

Comment: Edited my answer for windows

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any host what soever, then there isn't a server to run the php, the browser doesn't parse PHP, the server does, so if there isn't a server, none of the PHP gets parsed.

Comment: Thank you very much, can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: wait, you're just trying to open the php file in chrome?

Comment: see my answer now, you should checkout WAMP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file_path = "text_file.txt";
$file_handle = fopen($file_path, 'r'); // OPEN FILE READY FOR 'R'eading!
$text_data = fread($file_handle, filesize($file_path));  //Read actual data in file
print $text_data; // print the data you can use echo if you like
fclose($file_handle); // Close the file read / buffer


$data_to_write = "This is the data that will be written to disk!";
$file_path = "new_file.txt";
$file_handle = fopen($file_path, 'w');  // OPEN FILE READY FOR 'W'riting!
fwrite($file_handle, $data_to_write);
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: as much as this answer is good, i believe we just established that he's not actually running apache or anything, just trying to open the files in chrome...

Comment: Yea, realized that after i created the example code. He does not have apache / php installed whatsoever...  however, guess he'll come back with this issue, cause his code won't do what he wants it to do

Answer (score -1):

> I am not using any host whatsoever and am opening the files directly from my PC into Chrome.

You cannot run PHP files without a server (e.g. Apache). PHP files are 'server-side' scripts; the script is executed on the server, and the resulting output is send to the browser by the server.

See this question:

[Parsing PHP content in HTML without Webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838612/parsing-php-content-in-html-without-webserver)

Or try searching Google